# Geogebra Sum with x elements

Tags: graph, sum, geogebra

Is there a way to see the graph, using Geogebra, of a Sum, from 1 to x?

When i use the sum function, it seems like variables are not accepted, only numbers.

This is what I was trying to write: y=Sum(Sequence(i,i,1,((143091)/(x))))

Comment: How do you want the graph displayed exactly? Bar chart? Step graph?

Comment: I was just thinking about a line graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
n = 10
list = Sequence(i (i + 1) / 2, i, 1, n)
LineGraph(Sequence(n), list)
```

Comment: It says "illegal argument, number l1". Does it work for you?

Comment: Sorry, typo fixed. OK now?

Comment: Perfect, thanks! (grows sooo fast! :))